# Instructing ADODB Recordset to use SQL Server current timestamp

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb6, ado, recordset

I am attempting to write a number of records back to the database from a VB6 application using ADO. The records were read in from the database into an `ADODB.Recordset` and subsequently updated. I would like to be able to have each record in the set use the current date and time of the database server because I have no confidence that all our machines are time-synchronized. Is there a way to do this without having to query the database for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (or something similar)? Ideally I'm hoping for some sort of flag that I can set the field value to so that the `Recordset` works this out on the database server.

See the question in my prototype code below (within the while-loop).

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim oRs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sSQL As String
Dim sColumnName1 As String: sColumnName1 = "UserNID"
Dim sColumnName2 As String: sColumnName2 = "Username"
Dim sColumnName3 As String: sColumnName3 = "LastLoginDTM"

' Open a connection.
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.Open 'my connection string was here

' Make a query over the connection.
sSQL = "SELECT TOP 10 " & sColumnName1 & ", " & sColumnName2 & ", " & sColumnName3 & " " & _
       "FROM theTable"

Set oRs = New ADODB.Recordset
oRs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
oRs.Open sSQL, oConn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText
oRs.MoveFirst

While Not oRs.EOF
    oRs.Fields(sColumnName3).Value = '-=-=-=-=-What do I put here???-=-=-=-=-
    oRs.MoveNext
Wend

' Close the connection.
oConn.Close
Set oConn = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the TSQL [GetDate() Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx)

Change your Select to:

```
sSQL = "SELECT TOP 10 " & sColumnName1 & ", " & sColumnName2 & _ 
        ", " & sColumnName3 & ", GETDATE() AS ServerTimeStamp " & _
       "FROM theTable"
```

Then, your code could be:

```
While Not oRs.EOF
    oRs.Fields(sColumnName3).Value = oRS.Fields("ServerTimeStamp").Value
    oRs.MoveNext
Wend
```